# permission denied hive + oozie

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie

Getting below error when i am running oozie worflow. In oozie console under job configuration tab showing  hivesitepath property but is not loading.

```
    Launcher exception: hive-site.xml (Permission denied)
                java.io.FileNotFoundException: hive-site.xml (Permission denied)
                at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
                at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
                at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:110)
                at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain.setUpHiveSite(HiveMain.java:161)
                at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain.run(HiveMain.java:191)
                at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:38)
                at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain.main(HiveMain.java:66)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java
```

Comment: what is your `hivesitepath` ? Show your whole oozie job XML.

Comment: <configuration> 
<property>
    <name>hivesitePath</name>
    <value>hdfs://namenode-address/tmp/hive-site.xml</value>
  </property>
<property>
    <name>oozie.libpath</name>
    <value>/sharedlib,/sharedlib/hive,/sharedlib/pig</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>sql_user</name>
    <value>username</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>nameNode</name>
    <value>hdfs://namenodeaddress</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>jobTracker</name>
    <value>{jobtracker address}</value>
  </property>

</configuration>

Comment: hisesitepath: /tmp/hive-site.xml (this path in hadoop ) and i tried with another path too : /sharedlib/conf/hive-site.xml.

Answer (score 2):

I am using hue 3.6.0 in cloudera cdh5.1 and facing this issue, while using hive actions in oozie. The fix is to rename hive-site.xml to hive-config.xml in job.xml of oozie. It worked for me!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not set the right permissions after copying the hive-site.xml to oozie-workflow folder. Try    
  $sudo chown hdfs:hdfs oozie-workflows/hive-site.xml   
 Considering location and name of your oozie workflow folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, apparently fixed in version 3.6.0:

https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-1892